# SPSiteDataQuery with Number field

Tags: search

When executing search on a spweb using SPSiteDataQuery and using a field of type 'Number', the query does not always retun results, although the property query is correct and  it must return results.
When executing the same query on a document library ; use SPQuery instead of SPSiteDataQuery; on the same spweb, i get the right results.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a bug with the `SPSiteDataQuery` if you have more than 10 document libraries and/or lists in your site collection. You can read about it in the link below.

**Reference**:

[SPSiteDataQuery limited to 10 document libraries or lists](http://sharepointfieldnotes.blogspot.com/2009/09/spsitedataquery-limited-to-10-document.html).